# Getting undefined to a variable just after i used replace function for other values. in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use replace function with `words[i]` then variable res shows undefined when I trace it in Firebug and if I remove the replace code with `words[i]` then `res` works fine. Any help is appreciated.

```
function similitude(a, b) {
    for (var i = 0, len = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < len; i++)
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) 
            return Math.round(i / len * 100);
}

function ignorelines(){
    var l1 = $('#line1').val();
    var l2 = $('#line2').val();
    var contains = "";
    var contains2 = "";
    var res = "";
    var str = l1.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var str2 = l2.replace(/\s/g, '');

    $(".changeoccured .lines").each(function() {
        var words = $(this).text().split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var word = words[i].replace(/\s/g, '');
            contains += word;
        } 
        res = similitude(str, contains);
        if (res > 85) {                                           
            $(this).find('.leftchange').removeClass('leftchange');
        }
        contains = "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Could it be, that your replace is not returning anything, making contains empty .. have you tried outputting your contains to f.example console ?

Comment: First change `var res = "";` to `var res = 0;`  and var word = words[i].replace(/\s/g, ''); to var word = words[i].replace("/\s/g", '');

Comment: also your similitude function only returns if criteria is matched .. maybe you should also try to debug that part, seeing that it might not even return ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `similitude` function does not return anything (hence undefined) if both values are equal. So it means that one of the elements having `.lines` class had the same contents as the contents of the element with ID `line1`.

To fix this, have the function handle the case of equal strings:

```
function similitude(a, b) {
    if (a == b)
        return 100;
    for (var i = 0, len = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < len; i++)
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) 
            return Math.round(i / len * 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer is perfect. I was not looking into this function.. Thank you so much.